# Minipages wider than frame

Tags: minipage, width

In my document I have placed two mini pages side by side:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][6cm][t]{0.6\textwidth}
Some Text \\*
Some More Text
\vfill
Text \\
Text \\
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{Photo}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

However, the second (smaller) mini page extends beyond the frame of the document (as revealed by including `\usepackage{show frame}`).

[image]

The `fbox` boxes are just there for illustration, I do not want them in my final document.

I would like the right mini box to end exactly at the frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\noindent` to align the left mini page into the left margin. Also remove blank space between them. Note the use of `%`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b][6cm][t]{0.6\textwidth}
Some Text \\*
Some More Text
\vfill
Text \\
Text \\
\end{minipage}%  <-- here!!
\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{Photo}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

After removing the `\fbox{}` (which insert extra spaces) it looks fine.

[image]